# Xml serialization of List<IComponent> without specifying all derived types

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, derived-class

Let's say I have a container that contains instances of `IComponent` interface. Then I have many classes that implement this interface, for example `ComponentA`, `ComponentB`, ..., `ComponentY` and `ComponentZ`. Now I want to de/serialize it using Xml serialization with all my derived types. I know it's possible to list all the derived classes by using XmlArrayItem:

```
public class Xyz
{
    [XmlArray("Array")]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(ComponentA))]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(ComponentB))]
    // ... others
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(ComponentY))]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(ComponentZ))]
    public List<IComponent> Components;
}
```

But that's inflexible - I don't want to do it for every derived type, it's really painful for many derived types. Is there a way to do that without specifying all the derived types?